Why do certain control combinations result in longer sequences?
This is gonna be long so bear with me.
This is a coding problem to start with but the question I have about it seems like a math question, so I'm asking it here. The code itself isn't actually what I'm asking about.
Here is the original problem: https://adventofcode.com/2024/day/21
In summary: you need to input codes into a numeric keypad. To interact with the keypad, there is a robot arm in front of it that can be moved with a directional keypad. So you need to figure out what inputs you need to put into the directional keypad controlling the robot arm to get it to enter the correct input codes. However, for very convoluted reasons, you actually have to go through SEVERAL robots, each at a directional keypad controlling the next robot. So what inputs do you need to put into your keypad to get the next robot to put in the correct inputs into its keypad to get the next robot to put the correct inputs into ITS keypad ... to get the final robot to put in the codes.
The numeric keypad looks like this:
789
456
123
X0A

The directional keypads look like this:
X^A
<v>

The A key is the 'enter' key.
All robots start pointing at the A on their keypad.
The locations marked X the robot is not allowed to go over for any reason, not even traveling through them.
Everyone following???
The code I've written so far is very simple. I manually built dictionaries keyed by (x,y) pairs of characters storing strings of the input commands needed to move the robot arm from x to y. So, for example, if the robot needs to move from the A key to the 0 key, the dictionary has an entry of ('A','0') that stores the string "<", indicating that to move from A to 0 you need to press left once. From there, generating the inputs needed for any given result is simple: just index through the result you want one by one and look up the entry in the dictionary for (current index, next index) and append that to what the current output is.
Here, finally, is the math question.
Similar control sequences for specific keys should logically be the same, ie there should be no difference between traveling from A to 1 by going <^ vs ^<. But, for some reason, this is NOT the case. When traveling from 3 to 7, using the sequence <<^^ results in an overall SHORTER total sequence after going through all of the robots than if you were to use ^^<<.
Why!?!?
